# cumulative histogram equalisation in c

Tags: c, image-processing

I want to use cumulative histogram to achieve equalisation of the image. So I have the following steps:

1. loop through the image and compute the histogram.h[255]
2. convert the histogram to the cumulative histogram. c[255].
3. build a mapping function based on the cumulative histogram.
4. applying to the new image

In step 3, it's said that "In the ideal case the equalised image will contain an equal number of pixels having each grey value. So the j-th entry of the cumulative histogram will have the value j*N/L (where N is the sum number of pixels, and L is the number of grey value levels). This must be equated to an entry of C[i], so j = L*C[i]/N."

So should I get C[i], or to find j so as to achieve mapping?

In step 4, it is said that im_out[i][j] = c[im_in[i][j]], why does it work? Can somebody gives me a concrete example?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: why doesnt wikipedia count for you??

Answer (score 0):

I have already implemented histogram equalization (see function [Normalized Histogram](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd/blob/master/src/Simd/SimdBaseHistogram.cpp)).
I hope that you can find there something useful for you.